# Union of interfaces with a type field, create an object typed as: type - specific attribute of that types interface

Tags: typescript, union-types

This question is very hard to explain with words, and easy with code :-) Here's what I'm looking to achieve ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYUDeAsAFBSwAm5UAvGQOQCGldANCWQMJpwMI1R043XnRIBfANwkSSEAmAAnAGYM4eGJXjI0ABQaYANiiYF2UcBACMALnOQARoqmk7EAEy2Ljhc7HTisvLKqnhcIDwIWqggeobGVEQuAM4ICjZQKQqyAObOZJkeGak5vv6BiipqFORRaKYuZAg4wLa1GM0AdBrkeWRQ2PpGTK2aiNGxQz3iZXIVIVBhEW31fVBNuK1jaFi4HYu8vWQDccMLwpFbMYPxpcQk6%20qXSfzdywA%20Z%20G8bc4kQiApfrXJhJWwAJWAQgU5AAPG0dsAWLAngBtOjHSZ0AC6AD5%20IkyExyLYCX0APRkqCqNTYPhoAyYaptCbxMxiNguf4RElmMgUqlwGl0kAMz5LS4sphs8RAA))

```
enum ActionType {
  Add =  'add',
  Concat = 'concat'
};

interface AddActionPayload {
  num1: number;
  num2: number;
}

interface ConcatActionPayload {
  str1: string;
  str2: string;
}

interface AddAction {
    type: ActionType.Add;
    payload: AddActionPayload;
}

interface ConcatAction {
    type: ActionType.Concat;
    payload: ConcatActionPayload;
}

type Actions = AddAction | ConcatAction;

const payloads: Record<ActionType, Actions['payload']> = {
  add: {
    // accept only AddActionPayload
  },
  concat: {
    // accept only ConcatActionPayload
  }
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) in which the key and value types are completely uncorrelated.  It's of the form `type Record<K, V> = {[P in K]: V}`, where the key type of each key `P` (which iterates over the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of members of `K`) does not have any effect on the corresponding value type, which is `V` no matter what.  So you get behavior you don't like:

```
type Oops = Record<ActionType, Actions['payload']>;
/* type Oops = {
    add: AddActionPayload | ConcatActionPayload;
    concat: AddActionPayload | ConcatActionPayload;
} */
```

---

Instead, you should write a mapped type in which the value depends explicitly on the key.  Since you have an `Actions` union representing the information you want, the easiest thing to do is to map directly over `Actions` using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) in your mapped type to extract the key type as well as the value type.

It looks like this:

```
type Payloads = { [T in Actions as T['type']]: T['payload'] };
/* type Payloads = {
    add: AddActionPayload;
    concat: ConcatActionPayload;
} */
```

That behaves how you'd like:

```
const payloads: Payloads = {
  add: { num1: 1, num2: 2 },
  concat: { str1: "a", str2: "b" }
}; // okay

const badPayloads: Payloads = {
  add: { str1: "a", str2: "b" },
  concat: { num1: 1, nume2: 2 }
};  // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYUDeAsAFBSwAm5UAvFAOQCGldANCWQMJpwMI31xuvOiQC+AbhIkkIBMABOAMwZw8MSvGRoACg0wAbFEwLso4CAEYAXGcgAjBZNK2IAJhvmH8p6KnEZckoqeFwgPAiaqCC6BkZURM4Azgjy1lDJ8jIA5k5kGe7pKdk+fgEKyqoU5JFoJs4IOMA2NRiNAHTq5LlQ2HqGTM0aiFEx-V1ipbLlwVCh4S11ZA24zcNoWLhtc7zdvbEDs0IRa9F9cSXEJMtqJ4n8nQsAPodhvC1OV41QAPIo2He0ABKwEE8nIAB4WhtgCxYLcANp0PZjOgAXQAfE4APQAKig1x+fwBizIUCY5EG1ROoziUGe22OWlO+3GzjIgleCEpLRpxnpRx5ZyYPigOKxfgJvPIxPwUHh6CgMjhTLuDDu6ER1zRqJsGqRQvIaKgEhIuPxXylMtMZHJ3OpBu67KONgZgpZIrFfg5yR6BsSNkt-ASNsoNll5jSFlh5gKrmNbGcHPCYcKqRsACIGOnYfkM3Z08axOIoFisVAUABrPRetA+uxMS0Bv1B0y2giptKZ7Opgrp-Px0xJ3gpiM2KMuYCxwvECRkUtQBTyFDyACEfiAA)

Comment: Wow, never thought of using key remapping like that; [my take](https://tsplay.dev/w2zZrw) used `Extract` and is objectively more verbose.

Comment: Yeah, before key remapping, something like `Extract` was the only way to do it.  I'm pretty sure I remember ahejlsberg mentioning this as a motivating use case, but I don't see it in the pull request.  If I find the comment I'll link you to it.

Comment: I didn't know about key remapping, That's really clever! Thanks for the detailed explanation 